# Error in a Vue component method-with-debounce never gets reported

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling, vuejs2, vue-component

In a Vue component of the application I am working on, a method is called using `lodash.debounce` in order to reduce the number of calls. But I noticed that if any error occurs inside the debounced method, it is not reported to error watchers at the component level or app level.

Is there any way to report the errors in debounced methods?

Component Methods:

```
methods: {
  doMethod: function() {
    throw new Error();
  },
  doMethodDebounce: _.debounce(function() {
    throw new Error();
  }, 100)
},
```

Listening to errors in following ways:

In App.vue:

```
errorCaptured() {
  alert('Error in App.vue');
},
```

In main.js:

```
Vue.config.errorHandler = () => {
  alert("Error in main.js");
};
```

Please see the running example in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/p3zxo66xrq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why, but the workaround is to wrap the intended function body with [`$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick):

```
methods: {
  doMethodDebounce: _.debounce(function() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {

      // your potentially error-throwing code here

    })
  }, 100)
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mz1ko20lly?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue)

Comment: Thank you! .. It would work indeed but I am looking for handlers of run time exceptions where I am not throwing errors manually.  Please see this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/p3zxo66xrq

Comment: @JVM The idea is to put the intended function body inside `$nextTick`. I've [edited your example](https://codesandbox.io/s/y7vox1lr4j) to demonstrate.

Comment: Got it, so should we consider that it is the Vue way of capturing errors for Async methods?

Comment: No, that workaround is only required for `_.debounce`. Normally, you wouldn't have to do anything extra for Vue to capture async errors. I've updated the same example to show that Vue still captures errors from `async` functions (non-debounced).

Comment: Hi, it seems it would not work for the promises returned by stores.

Comment: Can you provide a repro? Best to ask as a new question